# import.io: how to query from c#

Tags: c#, httprequest, unauthorized, import.io

I am using import.io to perform some simple query. I need to automate the calls because of the quantity of queries, therefore I am writing a c# client to run all of them.

I can use the API query "magic string" as template to build my queries, if I manually paste them in a browser I see the JSon of the response.

Calling the urls by code instead I always get the 401 unauthorized error.

I tried to set the url to a web browser control, but it reports that site cannot be accessed.

**callingApi** is a string with the full url, composed as such (instead of **§** I have the url to be scraped):

https://api.import.io/store/connector/(connector code)/_query?input=webpage/url:**§**_apikeyadmin=(my key)

(same problem with _apikey instead of _apikeyadmin)

I tried

```
   WebRequest r = WebRequest.Create(callingApi);
                r.Method = "GET";
                using (var sr = r.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(sr))
                    {
                        var content = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
```

and also

```
   HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(callingApi);

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(callingApi).Result;  
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        ... here I have error 401
```

Any advice please?

Comment: Are you encoding (base64) your API key?

Comment: I do not call an encoding method, the key looks like 437f90f50ef79, total lenght 161 characters. It seems an HEX string, not a base 64. I will try.

Comment: Tried base 64 on key (and on other params in different combinations). I still have the 401 error. Official support says that I should ask here. It seems a trivial point and maybe I am making a fatal mistake, but I cannot go beyond the 401 error.

Comment: Did you read [their api documentation](http://api.docs.import.io/) (*if so you should have included a link in your question*)? Its really good and has examples and its interactive. Your problem is most likely due to wrong data or incorrect format of data, not the c# itself.